# How to enforce remote gnupg signing of Mercurial repository only when new tags are created?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I know how to configure the [Mercurial signing extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GpgExtension). The problem that I'm having is that I don't want to sign each individual change set, I only want to sign revisions that introduce new version tags.

That's easily accomplished locally, however I can't come up with a way to enforce this on the remote server. I'd like people to continue to be able to push their changes as normal, *unless* adding a release tag, which should be accompanied by a signature.

The end result should be that anyone cloning our repository can easily see a list of signed revisions, which point to a list of signed releases.

Hopefully, I've just missed something obvious in hooklib. Has anyone else accomplished this, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it on the server with a `pretxnchangegroup` hook.  More efficient in-process in python, but off the top of my head in shell you'd do:

In your hgrc:

```
[hook]
pretxnchangegroup = all-tags-checked.sh
```

and in all-tags-checked.sh:

```
for therev in $(seq $(hg id -n -r $HG_NODE) $(hd id -n -r tip)) ; do
   if hg log --template '{files}' -r $therev | grep --quiet '^.hgtags' ; then
      if hg sigcheck $therev | grep --quiet '^No valid' ; then
         exit 1
      fi
   fi
done
```

That goes through every new changeset and checks to make sure that if it edits .hgtags (add a tag) then it must also be signed.

Is that what you're looking for?